# .NET Function scope shadowing

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have seen some code like this (not on consecutive lines, but in the same function scope):

```vb
Dim con1 As SqlConnection
con1 = New SqlConnection
'More code here
con1 = New SqlConnection
con1 = Nothing
```

I believe this is just a bug, but I wanted to check that there is not a form of shadowing going on here that I am unaware of.  What happens to the first `con1` variable? I assume it is inaccessible as there is no reference to the object.

Comment: It's reassigned, and so is no longer accessible - the reference now points at a new instance of a SqlConnection. This can be a bad thing, especially if the connection was open at the time, as it will not be closed until the object is [non deterministically] disposed. Please (please!) always consider wrapping instances of SqlConnection, SqlCommand et al in a Using statement - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: For me it is a bug. The SqlConnection should be disposed with Close/Dispose or with the `using` statement. It's true that the garbage collector will handle the missing dispose, but what happen if this code is called in a very tight loop?

Comment: @Steve, will the garbage collector handle it?  I read somewhere that if you do not call either close or dispose then the connection object will hang around in the process memory until the process is recycled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What's Happening Here**

`con1` points to two different objects during the lifetime of that function.

The first object, created by the first

```
con1 = New SqlConnection
```

is no longer referenced after the second

```
con1 = New SqlConnection
```

is executed.

**Is this a memory leak?**

No.  The object that is no longer referenced will eventually be disposed of, then the GC decides to do so.  However it *is* a resource leak.  Every time you fail to close a SQL Connection (assuming it was opened and not just allocated), you leave a resource unavailable for reuse.  The GC will trigger when *memory* is low, so you will certainly regain the unreferenced object's *memory* at the latest when the system is low on memory (you will also regain the DB connection at that point).  However, low *resources* will *not* trigger GC.  You could run completely out of DB connections before the GC ever decides to kick in and release the SqlConnection objects (including the DB connections they were hoarding).

**Fixing the Code**

Since SqlConnection must be closed to release the connection, the first object will hang around until the GC decides to dispose of it.  *That is a bad thing*, as SQL connections are a resource that should only be held as long as necessary.

Calling Close() the first connection before assigning the new SqlConnection object would improve the situation (also, call Close() on the second instance before leaving variable scope).

However, if you get an Exception somewhere in the code, without proper exception handling, you would still be left with undisposed objects until the GC kicks in.  Always, always put exception handling around anything that manages a resource such as this.

The very best way to put exception handling in place for this scenario is with the [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword.  I have never written a line of VB.Net until now, but here's my attempt at a correct version of your code:

```
Dim con1 As SqlConnection

Using con1
    con1 = New SqlConnection
End Using

'More code here

Using con1
    con1 = New SqlConnection
End Using

' NOTE: I believe the following is unnecessary, but was necessary in VB6 and prior
' con1 = Nothing
```

Comment: No, it was never necessary in VB6 either (unless you had a circular reference situation, in which case yes, you had to break the chain manually).

Comment: Actually the constructor of `SqlConnection` does nothing which could cause a memory leak (all db stuff is done in `Connection.Open`). http://stackoverflow.com/a/8408475/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Granted, but it seems pretty reasonable that `'more code here` would actually do something with the connection :-)

Comment: @EricJ.: Yes, he should use `using-statement` to ensure that the connection gets closed. Otherwise it's not reusable for the [connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) which means that always a new physical connection must be created. So it's not the assignment of a "new" connection but the lack of closing the old connection.

Comment: Another way to always close the connection is to test for an open connection in the finally statement and close if necessary.  I think the general consensus is to use a Using statement though as you suggested in your answer.